# Confusion about how tangent vectors relate to vector fields in Differential geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-fields, tangent-spaces

**TL;DR:** I'm confused about some very basic definitions in Differential geometry, namely how tangent vectors and vector fields are related to each other.

---

Let $M$ be smooth manifold. My professor defined the *tangent vector*$^1$ $X\in T_p M$ as a linear map $C^\infty (M) \to \mathbb{R}$ which satisfies the derivation property
$$X(fg) = (Xf)g(p)+f(p)(Xg).$$

I already struggle here. Where exactly does the $p\in M$ on the rhs of the equation come from?  On the lhs, isn't there some information missing, or how exactly do we know at which point of $M$ we need to evaluate the functions?

He then further says that in "in any chart (representing $p\in U_p$) we have
$$X f=X^{i} f_{, i}(x): \quad X^{i}=X\left(x^{i}\right),$$
where $x^i\in C^\infty(U_p)$ denotes the coordinate function $p \mapsto x^i$. $^2$'' And here is where my real confusion starts. He then goes on to define what a *vector field* is, namely a linear map $X: C^\infty(M) \to C^\infty(M)$ with the derivation property
$$X(fg) = (Xf)g+f(Xg).$$

According to him it should now be clear what the "connection" between tangent vectors and vector fields is, but I find it really hard to piece anything together from what I described here.

It almost seems like all a vector field does is assign to every point on the Manifold a tangent vector in the tangent space, but I doubt that this is true after seeing his description...

---

$^1$ My professor only called it *vector*, but I think it is usually called tangent vector...

$^2$ Does he mean here that $x^i(p)\in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: " a vector field does is assign to every point on the Manifold a tangent vector in the tangent space" Yes, that's basically it, but normally one want to do it in a smooth, or at least a continuous, way.

Comment: To be honest I cannot find a more confusing way to teach what is $T_pM$. Note also that he defined elements in $T_pM$ to be linear map $C^\infty(M) \to \mathbb R$, which is inconsistent to the next paragraph, where they localize in a chart (which is not possible, at least he has to point out there's some cutoff argument).

Comment: The definition that I am aware of use "germs of smooth function at $p$" instead of the whole $C^\infty(M)$.

Comment: @ArcticChar Well, there are at least 4 ways to define what a tangent vector is, and which one is "obvious"/"confusing"/... depends on where you come from.

Comment: I think I still hold the opinion that the one using derivation is the most confusing one. It's not even clear that this is $n$-dimensional. @user10354138

Comment: About your first question, the $p$ appearing in the equation is the same point $p$ in $T_p M$, which is the tangent space in $p$.

Comment: @ArcticChar Not sure if it helps, but all of this was presented in the context of a general relativity lecture.

Comment: @FormulaWriter I see, but notation-wise it almost seems like a tangent vector and a vector field are the same thing. Is this intentional, standard or just a mistake?

Comment: @ArcticChar But it has the advantage of being coordinate-free.  Coordinate-free definitions and proofs are illuminating.  But I'd agree for a GR course you don't really want that to get in the way.  Better to leave that to a DG course.

Comment: Check out [Schuller's lectures](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLPH7f_7ZlzxTi6kS4vCmv4ZKm9u8g5yic). In particular, lecture 10.

Comment: Probably using the same letter $X$ to mean different things is not a good idea. But those two definition are different. For example, when $M= \mathbb{R}$ with the usual differential structure, the map $f\mapsto 45f'(0) $ is a tangent vector, the map $f \mapsto e^gf'$ is a vector field if $g$ is a smooth function.

Comment: @FormulaWriter is it correct to say that if we call $X_p$ a tangent vector, then a vector field is 
$$\begin{align*}
    X: M&\longrightarrow T_pM\\
    p&\longmapsto X_p
\end{align*}$$
and a tangent vector satisfies 
$$\begin{align*}
    X_p: C^\infty (M) &\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}\\
    f&\longmapsto X_p(f),
\end{align*}$$
where $X_p$ satisfies the derivation property.

Comment: According to what I was taught, yes, it is quite correct. You just need to add that $X$ must be smooth. It looks like your professor is using a different definition. Using the $X$ defined in your last comment, for every $f \in C^{\infty}(M)$ define $Y(f)\in C^{\infty}(M)$ in this fashion:
\begin{equation}
 (Y(f))(p)=(X(p))(f) \qquad \forall p \in M.
\end{equation}
Then $Y$ satisfies your professor's definition of vector field.

Comment: The way you describe it, your professor seems to be leaving out a lot of details. I suggest you to pick up an introductory DG text and go through the definition.

Comment: For your first question, no there is no missing information. The $p$ has the same meaning; it is the point at which we are considering the tangent space. Notice that $X(fg)$ is supposed to be a real number. $X(f)$ is a number, $g(p)$ is also a number. Similarly, $f(p)$ is a number, and $X(g)$ is also a number. We can add numbers and multiply them. The formula $X(fg) = X(f) \cdot g(p) + f(p) \cdot X(g)$ simply expresses the manner in which the LHS and RHS (both of which are numbers) are equal. Note that a tangent vector $X:C^{\infty}(M)\to\Bbb{R}$ has the real numbers as the target space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are various approaches to introduce tangent vectors and tangent spaces. I think the approach in your question is the most abstract one and perhaps not optimal for a beginner in the *motivational sense*. The general idea is that a tangent vector at a point $p  \in M$ is something like a *direction* in which you can go on $M$ starting at $p$.  There are various ways to make this precise, one of them is to describe a *direction* as a *directional derivative* applied to real valued smooth functions on $M$, i.e. by a certain operator $X$ assigning to any function $f \in C^\infty(M)$ a value $X(f) \in \mathbb R$. I give you a sketch, you have to fill missing details by consulting good textbooks.

For any manifold $M$, $C^\infty(M)$ is an algebra over $\mathbb R$, that is a real vector space with an additional commutative multiplication satisfying suitable compatibility requirements. Thus we get the vector space $L(C^\infty(M),\mathbb R)$ of linear maps $X: C^\infty(M) \to \mathbb R$. For each $p \in M$ define the subset
$$T_pM = \{ X \in L(C^\infty(M),\mathbb R) \mid \forall f,g :X(fg) = (Xf)g(p)+f(p)(Xg) \}.$$
It is easy to see that $T_pM$ is a linear subspace of  $L(C^\infty(M),\mathbb R)$ which is called the *tangent space of $M$ at $p$*. Each $X \in T_pM$ is a *tangent vector of $M$ at $p$*. In your question you write **the** tangent vector which is misleading because it suggests that there is only one.

This is fairly abstract and does not give much motivation. Let us therefore consider the simple special case where $M$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$. Then it is well-know from multivariable calculus what a directional derivative is: For each vector ("direction") $v \in \mathbb R^n$ and each differentiable $f :  M \to \mathbb R$ we define the directional derivative of $f$ at $p$ by $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial v}(p) = \lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{f(p + hv) - f(p)}{h}$. This gives us a linear map $X_v =\dfrac{\partial }{\partial v}\mid_p : C^\infty(M) \to \mathbb R$. Clearly $X_v$ satisfies the derivation property (in that case this is nothing else than the *product rule* for differentiation). It is well-known that $X_v = \sum_{i=1}^n v_i \dfrac{\partial }{\partial x^i}\mid_p$, where $v = (v_1,\ldots,v_n)$. The assocation $v \mapsto X_v$ gives us a linear map $\alpha: \mathbb R^n \to T_pM$ and it is not hard to show that $\alpha$ is a linear isomorphism. That is, we have a $1$-$1$-correspondence between directions $v \in \mathbb R^n$ (in which we can go on $M \subset \mathbb R^n$ starting at $p$) and elements of $T_pM$ (which are determined by their action on the functions in $C^\infty(M)$). Thus, although the elements of $T_pM$ at first glance seem to be very abstract and perhaps even incomprehensible, they are nothing else than ordinary directional derivatives which can be interpreted as *directions on $M$ at $p$*.

I hope this explains the above definition of $T_pM$ for a general $M$. In fact, the elements of $T_pM$ are directional derivatives in a generalized setting. This yields a concept of directions for a general $M$.

Your remark concerning the local representation of $X$ is rather vague, but I think a chart around $p \in M$ is a homeomorphism $x : U_p \to V$ (where $U_p$ is an open neighborhood of $p$ in $M$ and $V$ is open in $\mathbb R^n$) which belongs to the smooth structure of $M$. Then the $x^i : U_p \to \mathbb R$ are the $n$ coordinate functions of $x$. Now you have the problem that $x^i$ is in general not defined on all of $M$, but let us ignore it (it can be settled). Thus $X^i = X(x^i)$ is a real number. The meaning of $f_{,i}(x)$ is not clear, but I guess it is the $i$-th partial derivative of $f \circ x^{-1} : V \to \mathbb R$ at $x(p)$.

As you say, a vector field should associate to each $p \in M$ a tangent vector in $ T_pM$. This is what a linear map $\xi: C^\infty(M) \to C^\infty(M)$ with the derivation property does (I wrote $\xi$ instead of $X$  to avoid confusion - $X$ is used already for tangent vectors). In fact, given $p \in M$, define $\xi_p \in T_pM$ by $\xi_p(f) = \xi(f)(p)$. Note that $\xi(f) \in C^\infty(M)$. It is easy to verify that $\xi_p$ is linear and satisfies the derivation property required for tangent vectors of $M$ at $p$. The assignment $p \mapsto \xi_p$ is what we intuitively understand as a vector field. Working with $\xi$ is just another point of view.

So where is the direction information in $\xi_p$? We have $\xi_p \in T_pM$, and the elements of $T_pM$ are abstract directional derivatives, i.e. directions on $M$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! A short question: In your first paragraph, do I understand correctly that the analogy is that if $M\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ we have $\xi_p = \left.\frac{\partial}{\partial v}\right|_p$? If so, I'm a bit confused to where exactly the "direction" information went in your definition of $\xi_p$? I mean, in $\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial v}\right|_p$ it is clear that $v$ determines the "direction", but what determines the "direction" of $\xi_p$?

Comment: @MariusJaeger See my edit.